# Execute Powershell script in C# Unit Test

Tags: c#

Im trying to execute a powershell script to setup a vmware ENV before my Unit Test starts, in C#.

When im trying to execute the powershell script in a Program.cs , it works fine.

When i try to run it from a unit test the script dosent run and i can see an exception after the test starts.

`System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.`

Here is a sample code for a test im running:

```
using T;

namespace TTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Convert
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void convert()
        {
            Utility.prepC();
            string actual = Program.httpPost("http://10.1.1.1:1/aaa/bbb/ccc", "{\"id\":\"111\"}");            
            string expected = "true";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual,"true", "pass");          
        }
```

Here is the Utility class :

```
namespace T
{
    public class Utility
    { 
        static public void prepC()
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\C.ps1").Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling Powershell via the `Process` class instead?

Comment: If you mean inserting the code in the test himself , then yes i did try it.

Comment: No, I mean the good old `Process.Start()`

Comment: Hmm no i didnt, could you share an example on my code so ill what exactly you mean.

Comment: `Process.Start("powershell", @"-noprofile -command ""& 'C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\C.ps1'""")`

Comment: Same thing... When running in Program.cs it works.

When trying to run it in Unit Test it fails (powershell screen close so fast that i cant see if there is an error there).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution... the problem was , the c# code wasnt waiting for the powershell script to be done.

added

Process.Start("powershell", @"-noprofile -command ""& 'C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\C.ps1'""")
process.WaitForExit();

works now.